# How to generate a configuration failure in TestNG?

Tags: testing, testng

I'm trying to reproduce a particular case from my production environment. In which tests will be skipped after getting a Configuration failure. Is there a simple way to generate a Configuration failure in TestNG run?

Comment: Could you share some code which will help to understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: In our production system, we got a Configuration failure error causing all our tests being skipped. Unfortunately, we lost the logs which were generated. I'm not aware of what caused Configuration failure in TestNG for us. The failure happened only once, the tests run fine most of the times. I just wanted a simplest way we can configuration failure in Testng?

Comment: Configuration failure is produced when an exception is thrown in a `@BeforeX` method. The stacktrace should be provided in the TestNG report. And if you want to configure the failure behavior, you can change the  `configfailurepolicy` (see http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just reiterating what was discussed in the above comments for the benefit of other people looking for an answer.

It is very easy to raise configuration failure issue in testng. All you have to do is throw an exception in any `@Before` method. Note that an exception will prevent the tests from execution. Unless you exclusively mention it.

```
public class someTest {
      @BeforeClass 
      public beforeClassMethod() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception();
            // this will cause a configuration failure
      }

     @Test()
     public void someTest() {
            // will be skipped
     }
}
```